# Include в зависимости от текущего года

Tags: php, include

Хочу сделать чтобы в 2021м году срабатывал инклюд  './sys/news7.php' а в другие года - './sys/news2.php'.

Вот код страницы:

```
<?php

$startyear == 2021;

if($startyear == date('Y')) {include './sys/news7.php'; } else {include './sys/news2.php'; }
; 


?>
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: нет, это вы скажите в чём ошибка?

Comment: и да `$startyear == 2021;` ---> `$startyear = 2021;`

Comment: срабатывает инклюд ...news2.php даже в 2021м году

Comment: отладчик включи и забудешь за такие мелкие косяки..

Comment: а дебаггер куда устанавливать если сайт на сервере в интернете?

Comment: неужели ты кодишь на хостинге?

Comment: на бесплатном )

Comment: Для начала всегда ведите разработку локально. Так проще и ошибки исправлять  и отлавливать как минимум.